# Отличия data-атрибутов в html от классов

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Не могу понять, чем отличаются data-атрибуты и классы в HTML...И то и то подходит для стилизации элементов..

Comment: А еще для стилизации элементов подходят атрибуты `id`, `name`, `src` и многие другие. Но это не означает, что их следует для этого использовать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для стилизации элементов лучше всего подходят классы, тк классы имеют ряд преимуществ:

1. Классы имеют наименьший приоритет (Это значит, что их легко перезаписать: браузер читает правила сверху вниз). В отличие от классов id имеет наибольший приоритет: это значит, что перезаписать свойства селектора id можно только, если один из селекторов - id (Например, перезаписать #title со свойством можно: после #title или использовать вложенность, например, #element h1 или #element .title). Также лучше не использовать селекторы по типу элемента, тк правила применяются ко всем выбранным элементам (Например, h1, p. Лучше использовать класс, например, .title, .text).
2. Простое использование (Можно напрямую обращаться к элементу: без вложенности. Например, .title, .sidebar, .footer).

Data-атрибуты нужны для валидной верстки, чтобы работать с JavaScript.

Comment: 3. Браузеры быстрее работают с классами чем с произвольными атрибутами

Comment: @AlexeyTen, зависит от браузера